# When in malloc does the PREV_INUSE bit mean that mchunk_prev_size is meaningful?

Tags: malloc

Something I don't understand in a comments by Colin Plumb in the malloc.c source file [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.27.tar.gz).

In the comments of the malloc_chunk "structure", I read that :

> The P (PREV_INUSE) bit, stored in the unused low-order bit of the chunk size (which is always a multiple of two words), is an in-use bit for the *previous* chunk. If that bit is *clear*, then the word before the current chunk size contains the previous chunk size, and can be used to find the front of the previous chunk.

This is also what you can read in [this issue](http://www.phrack.org/issues/57/8.html) of Phrack magazine commenting Doug Lea's Malloc:

> If the PREV_INUSE bit of a chunk p is set, the physical chunk of memory located immediately before p is allocated, and the prev_size field of the chunk p may therefore hold user data. But if the PREV_INUSE bit is clear, the physical chunk of memory before p is free, and the prev_size field of the chunk p is therefore used by dlmalloc and contains the size of that previous physical chunk.

So if I understand well, this would mean that if bit P value is 0, then the mchunk_prev_size in the current chunk gives the size of the previous chunk. This is consistent with the drawings in mallo.c.

My problem is that later in the code in the code of malloc.c, I read this :

```
/* size field is or'ed with PREV_INUSE when previous adjacent chunk in use */
#define PREV_INUSE 0x1

/* extract inuse bit of previous chunk */
#define prev_inuse(p)       ((p)->mchunk_size & PREV_INUSE)

/* Size of the chunk below P.  Only valid if prev_inuse (P).  */
#define prev_size(p) ((p)->mchunk_prev_size)
```

If I understand well, it would mean that the mchunk_prev_size in the current chunk gives the size of the previous chunk if bit P in the current chunk is set to 1, and not 0, as told in the previous explanations.

So did I miss something, or is there some inconsistency here about what value of P tells that mchunk_prev_size gives the size of the previous chunk or not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For the people who may face the same problem, here is the explanation. There was a mistake in the comments in version 2.37 of glibc:

```
/* Size of the chunk below P.  Only valid if prev_inuse (P).  */
#define prev_size(p) ((p)->mchunk_prev_size)
```

The comments in a later version of glibc such as 2.39:

```
/* Size of the chunk below P.  Only valid if !prev_inuse (P).  */
#define prev_size(p) ((p)->mchunk_prev_size)
```

Notice the missing "!" before prev_inuse...

And by the way, the explanation of malloc() in the previously cited Phrack is far the best you can read on the Web, and maybe elsewhere.